# Unable to set static IP at boot with Debian 9 on Beaglebone Black

Tags: linux, networking, bash, debian, ip

## Summary

I am trying to set a static IP on a beaglebone black system. (Running Debian 9)

Thus far, I have tried;

- editing /etc/network/interfaces
- creating a shell script and running it from systemd

Neither method has worked so far. I will give a detailed explaination of both at the end of this post, however before this:

- What is the correct (most sensible) way to set a static IP with Debian 9? Is it the case that there are many possible methods, and that they are all equally as valid?

A few things to point out:

- I know that `ifconfig` is different from `ip` and that `ip` has "replaced" the older program `ifconfig` - however on my system both commands work. I have no idea why this is the case. `ifconfig` is not an alias for `ip addr` as the output is different. I have no idea what the difference between them is.
- I know essentially nothing about systemd and I have just copied information I found online [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux)

## Details

- **/etc/network/interfaces**

I have added the lines

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (redacted for obvious reasons)
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

When I reboot, and run either `ifconfig` or `ip addr` I can see that eth0 has a completely different ip to the one I "assigned" in `/etc/network/interfaces`

I thought this would work as this method is familiar to me. So I don't understand what is going wrong or how to test / debug this.

- **systemd**

I made a shell script in `/home` which sets the ip manually. The shell script contains;

```
ifconfig eth0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX eth0
```

plus one additional debugging line

```
echo "systemd" > /home/test.txt
```

If I run this script as root (it is owned by root) from the bash command line, then the ip is changed as expected. (`ifconfig` shows the expected static ip)

I tried to get systemd to exec this script by adding a new file in `/etc/systemd/system` called `network-set-static-ip.service`

The file `/etc/systemd/system/network-set-static-ip.service` contains

```
[Unit]
After=networking.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/set_ip_static.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have never used systemd before, and I haven't got a clue if any of this is correct, or whether it is just totally wrong.

Restarting the system does **not** result in the file `/home/test.txt` being created, so I think systemd is **not** running the script `/home/set_ip_static.sh`.

Is there anything obvious I have done wrong? Is there any way to debug systemd somehow and find out what is going wrong?

## Conclusion

I should conclude by saying I do not care which method I use to get the ip address set statically. It can be either of these two or something completely different if there is a better alternative.

As long as when the system boots, the IP is set to the static value, then that is good enough.

Comment: If `network-manager` package is installed and `network-manager.service` runs, the configuration is in `/etc/NetworkManager/` and the main tool is `nmcli`. Your desktop environment (if any) may have its own GUI tool to configure the manager. What is the output of `systemctl status network-manager.service`? I think I have uninstalled the package in my Debian and now `/etc/network/interfaces` works.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It says that service does not exist. I believe I have the GUI version installed. But `startx` reports command not found... Is startx called something else on this system? Is there a way to check whether I have a gui or network manager installed? `nmcli` is also another command not found...

Comment: OK, so it's not Network Manager. I'm not able to help you further (at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

## Note

This answer is not "an answer" to either of the two problems/issues specified in the question above, however it is a possible alternative that works.

## References:

https://elritsch.github.io/2017/08/02/execute-script-at-linux-startup.html

https://elritsch.github.io/2017/08/02/execute-script-at-linux-startup.html

## Steps

This works with Debian 9 which uses systemd.

1. Create a script that you want to run, eg `/home/script.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x /home/script.sh`)
2. Create a file `/etc/rc.local` which used to exist with SysVinit systems, make it executable
3. Create `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service`. Add this content

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local
    
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Edit `/etc/rc.local`, add this content

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/home/script.sh #add this line to exec script/commands

exit 0
```

5. Ensure all scripts are executable and enable the systemd service with `systemctl enable rc-local`
6. Reboot

**Keywords:** systemd sysv sysvinit debian 9 linux run startup script at boot